# Google Drive Sqlite db upload not working

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-android-api

I want to backup and restore my sqlite db. For this i am using google drive api. I have used this [this](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) demo code. All works perfect. I can upload and download my db until i uninstall my app.

But then i notice a strange behavior. The scenario is as follow

- Enter Some data to sqlite
- Upload my sqlite db to drive
- Uninstall my application
- Re-install it and try to download file from drive.

  At this time i cant found any file from drive....search returns 0 always...i dont know why. All works perfect if i dont uninstall app and just clear data.

Here is my code for uploading....

```
public boolean createFile() {
        DriveId dId = null;
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("db");

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            try {
                DriveFolder pFldr = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
                if (pFldr != null) {
                    File file = context.getDatabasePath(db.getDatabaseName());
                    DriveContents cont = file2Cont(null, file);
                    MetadataChangeSet meta = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(Google_Drive_File).
                            setMimeType(mimeType).build();
                    DriveFolder.DriveFileResult r1 = pFldr.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, meta, cont).await();
                    DriveFile dFil = r1 != null && r1.getStatus().isSuccess() ? r1.getDriveFile() : null;
                    if (dFil != null) {
                        DriveResource.MetadataResult r2 = dFil.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                        if (r2 != null && r2.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            dId = r2.getMetadata().getDriveId();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        return dId == null ? false : true;
    }
```

Please help me....

Comment: Are there also any error/s that appears in the logs? Please share.

Comment: no there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i have solved it....i was not getting file because i was using debug key in auth certificate. All works perfect as soon as i change my debug key with release.

Comment: Hi can u share the approach  for me